# Efficient way to apply function between two pandas rows across the whole DataFrame

Tags: pandas, loops

I have a Pandas data frame:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(index=['C1','C2','C3'],data={'X1':[0.3,10,34],'X2':[4,7.5,0.1],'X3':[0,0,1.7],'X4':[1.5,11,1],'X5':[1,0.1,0.6]})
```

And a function that takes as an input 2 Pandas series:

```
def SomeFunction(Series1,Series2):
    
    s = Series1.sum()
    m = Series2.max()
    
    return sqrt(s)^6+3*m/56
```

What I need is to iterate through all the row combinations and return results in the following data frame:

```
         C1          C2          C3
C1  314.646     23393.9     52313.8
C2  315.021     23394.2     52314.2
C3  316.253     23395.5     52315.4
```

My current solution is:

```
R = pd.DataFrame(index=['C1','C2','C3'],columns=['C1','C2','C3'])
for i in X.index:
    for j in X.index:
        R.loc[j,i] = SomeFunction(X.loc[i],X.loc[j])
```

However, the data frame X has 9000 rows and 1200 columns, and this approach is too slow.
Also, the function is more complex.

**Is there a more efficient way to do these calculations?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "The function is more complex."  Great, show us the actual code so we can work on it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The real function is "similarity.py" from the package FPKit, and the input data frame is binary. One can set a threshold at 1 to binarize the X data frame from above, ie. if a value in the cell is below 1 it is 0, otherwise, it is 1.

Comment: This one?  https://github.com/davidbajusz/fpkit/blob/master/similarity.py  That code is a performance disaster.  Are you willing to rewrite it, or you need to use that code as it is?

Comment: That code really is bad, and it looks like it is possible to vectorize this similarity function (analogous to my answer below). But some time would have to be spent understanding that file..

Comment: Yes, that is the correct function. I plan to use it. That is the only package that implements a similarity score that I need in my research.

Comment: OK.  Your goal is to speed up the overall calculation, right?  You should start by copying that library code and modifying it, first by simplifying it to remove all code paths you don't actually need, and the disgusting `str(type(x))` stuff.  Trying to optimize the Pandas side where you call the function won't give you nearly the sort of speedup you'll get by optimizing the library code in this case.

Comment: Yes, you are right; I got it. Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is: `(sqrt(s)**6)` + `(3 * m / 56)`

You can use vectorization to create a small data frame with columns holding both sides of your summation (i.e., one with `sqrt(s)**6` and another with `3*m/56`).

```
df = pd.concat([df.sum(1).rename('sum'), df.max(1).rename('max')], 1)
df['sum'] = np.sqrt(df['sum']) ** 6
df['max'] = df['max'] * 3/56
```

Which outputs:

```
          sum       max
C1    314.432  0.214286
C2  23393.656  0.589286
C3  52313.624  1.821429
```

Then, you can just [`outer` sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) them.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.add.outer(df['max'].values, df['sum'].values))
```

```
            0             1             2
0  314.646286  23393.870286  52313.838286
1  315.021286  23394.245286  52314.213286
2  316.253429  23395.477429  52315.445429
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach, but I am looking for a solution where one would apply a function across the data frame. The function I showed is just an example. The real function is similarity.py from the package FPKit.

Comment: `pd.concat([df.sum(1).pow(3).rename('sum'), df.max(1).mul(3/56).rename('max')], 1)` so you can skip below two lines.

Comment: From [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) [We recommend using `DataFrame.to_numpy()` instead](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)

Comment: There is no point bike shedding this answer when it won't help OP because the real code is something else entirely.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Agreed but wanted to propagate standard usage(i'm sure rafaelc already knows them) but a beginner user might not know them. I upvoted answer already.